# How to find select_list selected options when id is dynamic using page-objects

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

When an item is added to a cart it willI have a five select_lists within a div that I need to get the selected option for using the page-object gem.

The code looks like this:

```
<div id='item_basket_235423423'>
  <select_list id = 'fruit_23423423'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'fruit_24533424'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'fruit_26352321'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'fruit_23462425'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'fruit_23346342'>...</select_list>
</div>
<div id='item_basket_23423464'>
  <select_list id = 'veg_684341'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'veg_65181351'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'veg_86516843'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'veg_21676919'>...</select_list>
  <select_list id = 'veg_9831568'>...</select_list>
</div>
```

This finds all the select_lists:

```
select_lists(:selected_basket_fruits, :id => /fruit/)
select_lists(:selected_basket_vegetables, :id => /veg/)
```

From here I am not really sure how to find the selected option for each one. I am using ruby/cucumber/watir-webdriver and the page-object gem.

As always your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accessor:

```
select_lists(:selected_basket_fruits, :id => /fruit/)
```

Will define a method that returns a collection of matching select lists:

```
selected_basket_fruits_elements
```

This is an [enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html), so you can iterate over it with methods like `each`. When iterating, you can use the [`selected_options`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Platforms/WatirWebDriver/SelectList#selected_options-instance_method) method of select lists to determine the selected options.

```
page.selected_basket_fruits_elements.each do |select_list|
  p select_list.selected_options
end
```

Note that `selected_options` returns an array of selected options.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I will give that a try. I tried something similar but had no luck which is why I asked.

Comment: If I wanted to push this code to the page file rather than my steps how would I wait for these select_lists to be present. I tried selected_basket_fruits_elements.when_present do ... but I get a when_present undefined. Same issue with when_visible.

Comment: Waiting for a collection of elements is a little bit more complicated. You need to be able to explain (to the code) what to wait for - ie what does it mean for the collection to be present? Do you expect there to be a certain number of elements or do you just want to proceed when there is at least one element in the collection?

Comment: I just ended up waiting for the first element to be present. Thanks for your help.